How is this sentence feauturing an embeded question divided?
伊波「探すか？」
腕組みをし、強く眉を寄せた伊波が提案した
捜索について問いかけであったのは、他の方法が考えられるかどうか、三貴子への伺いもあるのだろう
けれど三貴子は悩む素振りも見せず同意した。
I'm a lil confused on I should interpreted the third sentence here. In the first line, the character ask if they should search for the missing man to his boss. Following some description, the  narration then describes what I assume what the question itself involves?
Finally, it concludes that 貴子 doesn't look worried and agrees.
"
捜索について問いかけであったのは、他の方法が考えられるかどうか、三貴子への伺いもあるのだろう"
From context my reading would be akin to "In the question for the search it's also included if she can think of other methods" but it's purely speculative from my party. How are the 3 elements of the sentence interacting here? Is there something omitted?

Does the text really go 捜索について問いかけであったのは, instead of, like, についての問いかけ or について問いかけた?

I just checked it and yet. I copy pasted it from the VN anyway.

Is VN visual novel? If so, what is the title?
